# UIAlertView for No Matches Found in Search

Tags: ios, uialertview, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar on my MKMapView that searches the maps annotations.  I'm trying to incorporate an alert that lets the users know if no matches were found.  The problem is that the alert comes up even when a match is found and when I click the cancel button the alert comes back up.  Any suggestions?

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    id<MKAnnotation> ann;

    for (int i = 0; i < [marketLocations count]; i++)
    {
        for (ann in marketLocations)
        {
            NSString *annTitle = ann.title;
            NSString *annSubtitle = ann.subtitle;
            NSString *searchText = [searchBar text];
            NSRange titleRange = [annTitle rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
            NSRange subtitleRange = [annSubtitle rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

            if (titleRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [worldView selectAnnotation:ann animated:YES];
            }
            else if (subtitleRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [worldView selectAnnotation:ann animated:YES];
            }
            else if (titleRange.location == NSNotFound || subtitleRange.location == NSNotFound)
            {
                UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"No Matches Found" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [av dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
                [av show];
            }
        }
    }

    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Is just me, or the first `for` loop doesn't need top be there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `BOOL` at the beginning called `annotationFound`. When the annotation is found, set `annotationFound` to YES. Move the alert out of the for loop and into an `if` at the end based on `annotationFound`.